# Binding event on elements having "left: 0px"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<span class="switchery switchery-small" style="box-shadow: rgb(223, 223, 223) 0px 0px 0px 0px inset; border-color: rgb(223, 223, 223); transition: border 0.4s, box-shadow 0.4s; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <small style="left: 0px; transition: background-color 0.4s, left 0.2s;"></small>
</span>
```

I'm using a plugin and it generated above code. How can I select switchery that it has small tag that its left is 0px?

I wrote this

```
if ($('.switchery').find('small').attr('style').indexOf('0px') > -1) {

}
```

but how can I apply `click()` my matches element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function) with callback.

1. Select all the `<small>` elements inside `.switchery` element
2. Filter the elements having `left` property zero

```js
var smallEl = $('.switchery small').filter(function() {
  return parseInt($(this).css('left')) === 0;
}).css('color', 'green');

smallEl.click(function() {
  console.log('Hello');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="switchery switchery-small" style="box-shadow: rgb(223, 223, 223) 0px 0px 0px 0px inset; border-color: rgb(223, 223, 223); transition: border 0.4s, box-shadow 0.4s; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
  <small style="left: 0px; transition: background-color 0.4s, left 0.2s;">Left 0</small>
  <small style="left: 100px; transition: background-color 0.4s, left 0.2s;">Left 100</small>
  <small style="transition: background-color 0.4s, left 0.2s;">No Left</small>
</span>
```

Comment: wow didn't know filter can be used like this! awesome! but is it nessarcy to use .css('color',green);? what's that for?

Comment: @JenniferAniston That's just for Demo purpose. To give visual clue what the result of `filter` is returned.

Comment: so it's ok if the .css() is not there?

Comment: @JenniferAniston Yes, you  can remove it

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this :

```
if ($('.switchery').has('small').find('small').css('left') == '0px') {
    // if matches
    // do click operation here
    $('.switchery').click()
    // or
    $('.switchery').click(function () {...
    });
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/4ya36vag/)

Comment: **1** No need of `has('small')`. **2** If there are multiple elements `.find('small').css('left')` will not work as expected **3** OP wants to bind event on element having `left: 0px;`. **4** This doesn't work as expected. Check updated [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/4ya36vag/2/).

Comment: I have to use $(this) because I have more tags.

Comment: more tags of what. `$('.switchery')` or `small`

Answer (score 0):

Try using selector `$(".switchery small[style*='left\\: 0px']")`

```js
$(".switchery small[style*='left\\: 0px']").click(function() {
  alert(this.textContent)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="switchery switchery-small" style="box-shadow: rgb(223, 223, 223) 0px 0px 0px 0px inset; border-color: rgb(223, 223, 223); transition: border 0.4s, box-shadow 0.4s; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <small style="left: 0px; transition: background-color 0.4s, left 0.2s;">0px</small>
</span>
<span class="switchery switchery-small" style="box-shadow: rgb(223, 223, 223) 0px 0px 0px 0px inset; border-color: rgb(223, 223, 223); transition: border 0.4s, box-shadow 0.4s; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <small style="left: 1px; transition: background-color 0.4s, left 0.2s;">1px</small>
</span>
```